# Textmate: remap Escape for word completion

Tags: textmate

In the Textmate code-editor I use the Escape-key, for word completion, alot.
Is there a way to bind another key-shortcut to its functionality ?

(ps: my CAPSLOCK is already CTRL)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remap the <kbd>esc</kbd> key you have to copy

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict
```

to

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict
```

and then edit it, preferably using TextMate :) as Property List Editor messes up the codes.

Look for **`nextCompletion`** and **`previousCompletion`** and replace their values with whatever suits your needs best. 
For example, you could replace `\033` (code for <kbd>esc</kbd>) to `\t` (<kbd>->|</kbd>).

Comment: This is cool, but now my tab doesn't work to add 2 spaces like it used to. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: @andi: I'm amazed your answer doesn't have more votes. I like this approach more than anything. Maybe this is how it was designed to be?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Mac OSX Yosemite w/ TextMate2. Anyone else have a similar issue? (Or any step after this that I'm missing?) I tried both  "\t"    = "previousCompletion:";
  "\t"    = "nextCompletion:"; and  "~\t"    = "previousCompletion:";
  "~\t"    = "nextCompletion:"; in mate ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict

Answer (score 14):

A much better way to do this (and this applies to all Mac apps in general) is to

- Open System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Keyboard shortcuts
- Click the + sign at the bottom
- Choose TextMate from the application menu
- Type the exact name of the menu command for next completion and previous completion
- Now type the shortcut you want to use and click the Add button

Comment: the escape and tab key functionality does not have menu commands.

Comment: The escape key's menu command should be "Next Completion" (Edit > Completion > Next Completion). (Similarly you could also map "Previous Completion" -- I have mine mapped to Command+K and Command+Shift+K, and they work fine).

Comment: Just realized my solution no longer works in TextMate 2. Upvoting andi’s answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the most modern version of TextMate.  Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, but this answer is better if it works.  I already did the other answer and it works fine.. but I'd rather have not.